# What is the relation between the saros (18 years, 11 days, 8 hours) and the period of lunar nodal precession (18.6 years)?

Tags: the-moon, solar-eclipse, lunar-eclipse

I am wondering. I am sure that they are related. How can we derive one from the other?

Comment: The relationship appears to be strongly related to the difference between sidereal and draconic months.   You might start by looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_precession  and the reference documents listed there.